# very slow internet connection on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

My Internet is very slow since I upgraded to ubuntu 14.04
Here is all info I got
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7317131/

Comment: See also: [Internet slow on Ubunte 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470279/internet-slow-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3):

**Fix the bug in Debian Avahi-daemon**

The slow WiFi in Ubuntu problem could also be related to a bug in Avahi-daemon of Debian. Ubuntu and many other Linux distribution are based on Debian so this bug propagates to several Linux distributions. To fix this bug, you have to edit the nsswitch configuration file. Open a terminal and use the following command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

This will open the configuration file in gedit so that you could edit it easily in GUI. In here, look for the following line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

If you find this file, replace it with the following line:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Save it, close it, restart your computer. It should fix the slow wireless connection problem for you. If it doesn't check the other solution.

If this dosen't work, try other solutions from [here](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/).

Comment: or `sudo sed -i 's/files mdns4_minimal \[NOTFOUND=return\] dns/files dns/' /etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: Changing the hosts: entry worked for me.  Thanks!