# Super slow Internet on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, dell

This has been asked tons of times, that's why I've tried out a couple of solutions and since none of the stuff worked, decided to ask for help here (as a last/desperate resort).

I own a **Dell Inspiron 15R** and have been using Ubuntu 14.04 for a couple of weeks. Fairly new to this world, but was determined to get away from Windows. So I'm running this baby with two partitions

1. Ubuntu 14.04
2. Windows 8.1

I've disabled ipv6, edited [nsswitch and conf files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470279/internet-slow-on-ubuntu-14-04)

**E.g. newly added in [sysctl.conf](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/disable-ipv6-if-your-internet-is.html)**

```
#disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.core.rmem_default = 524288
net.core.rmem_max = 524288
net.core.wmem_default = 524288
net.core.wmem_max = 524288
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 87380 524288
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 524288
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 524288 524288 524288
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1
net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_ecn = 0
net.ipv4.route.flush = 1
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A2**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4462]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Here's the **[speed test](http://www.speedtest.net/result/4673443046.png)**.

Please help me, I'm at the end of my tether. 
True story. :'(

Comment: In hindsight, I should've made some notes on WHAT I've done so far, but have neglected to do so. Ugh. The points I listed in the post before, are the ones off the top of my head that I have a recollection of.

Comment: How do you connect to internet? By wire?

Comment: Please go to speedtest.net and paste your results

Comment: @Pilot: wireless, yep

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Hi @DavidCole, I've added the speed test!

Comment: Look at this question. Your one is a duplicate. http://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter

Comment: Do you use bluetooth? Try other options from that answer too.

Comment: @Pilot6 I ran this command `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"` and after rebooting, I noticed a slight improvement but not by much. See the [speed test](http://www.speedtest.net/result/4673691043.png)

Comment: @Monticora You can use other options too. And answer please regarding bluetooth.

Comment: I've done that... by which I mean: "_enable all of the options and removing them one by one to test which one does the trick_". It didn't really work/make a difference. To answer your question about **bluetooth**-- It's always switched on, even when I switch it off, somehow it switches itself back on. I don't know why this keeps happening, really weird, I gotta admit. You think bluetooth has smth to do with the slow internet?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and worked fine for me.
Try adding OpenDNS server to your IPv4 setting

```
208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the connection, It's slightly [improved](http://www.speedtest.net/result/4678872626.png). But I'm still looking for something I can do additionally. I'm used to a much faster wireless connection, it's really frustrating and upsetting.

Comment: The internet speed seems to continually fluctuate. I just tested it again and it said ca. 2.5 Mbps. May I ask how fast yours is?

Comment: I am getting 4.0 - 5.5 mbps fluctuating speed of 16 mpbs wireless broadband connection

Comment: My wireless connection is 54Mbps, but as mentioned it doesn't even scratch the surface in that regard, since I get 2.5Mbps

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871477

try this hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and then type `iwconfig`
If you are getting this output :-

> ppp0      no wireless extensions.
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
> Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=19 dBm
> Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
> **Power Management:on**

Then try disabling your power management on Wi-Fi. This will increase your continuity in speed but will consume your battery 2% to 3% faster.

To disable this

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

Copy and paste below into the empty file and save it.

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Now you need to change the permission

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

Now restart your system. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and my computer's power management is already switched off.