# Internet acts very strange on youtube and google and other sites - 14.04

Tags: internet, browser

I have 14.04. I have tried Firefox, Chrome and Chromium, but I get the same problem on all 3. Sometimes sites will just stop loading. It happens all the time on Google (clicking a link on the search results) and YouTube (the video will just stop playing). I installed Ubuntu about a week ago and this has been a constant problem, and I'm thinking about giving up with Ubuntu and just going back to Windows, as I have never had this problem there and I use Google/Gmail/YouTube so much that's it's too inconvenient to have to deal with this. Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is it your Internet connection? Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470279/internet-slow-on-ubuntu-14-04 ).

Comment: I notice the sites you name. Try changing your DNS settings to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` and let us know if that works. If it does, I'll write up an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @KGIII I did try that already, and it didn't help :(

Comment: Alright. What do you have for extensions running in your browser?

Comment: @KGIII None. It has been like this since I installed Ubuntu a week ago. No extensions (unless they come with ones by default) on Firefox, Chrome, or Chromium. I did find a solution on here (forgot exactly where but I'll try to find it) that said to block cookies from Google, and I did that and it seemed to fix the issue, but I'm going to wait until tomorrow to see if it continues to work.

Comment: This is odd - I am thinking it's something at your ISP or with your connection - as the rest of the 'net is working. Google had some infrastructure issues with their fiber the other day. You can install `traceroute` and then do `traceroute google.com` and see if there's a specific hop with a high degree of latency.

Comment: I don't know what it is, but I know it's not my connection. I can hop onto Windows (on the same computer) and it works perfectly fine :(. It seems like blocking Google from storing cookies might have helped but I'll wait to see if it sticks. It will be annoying not being able to use cookies for Google though.

Comment: How do you connect to the internet? Is the connection stable? Do you experience packet loss? You can check for it with `ping -qc 60 www.google.com` (takes ~1 minute) and post the output here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hi. I connect wired through a router. My brother is the only other person on the router, and I know it's not an issue of him downloading something or anything like that, as I use the internet more than him. I just want to point out again that I have never had issues with my internet in Windows. Anyway, here is what I go with that command:

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
60 packets transmitted, 60 received, 0% packet loss, time 59051ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 25.592/26.900/61.138/4.475 ms

Comment: We have a fantastic [diagnostic page for WiFi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205).  Go there first and then [edit] your question and report back on the results.