# My internet is very slow and freezes-unfreezes-freezes-unfreezes (16.04)

Tags: command-line, wireless, 16.04, internet

I'm wondering if there's a command I can write in Terminal to search for and update any outdated things (like network drivers, adapters, etc)?

I have a Lenovo ideapad. When it ran Windows 7, the Internet was perfect.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 [8086:0891] (rev c4)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 BGN [8086:4222]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the title of your question (about unstable internet) is related to the question inside the body (about software updates). Both are manageable but we need to understand what you want. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: The output of the lspci command is 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 [8086:0891] (rev c4)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 BGN [8086:4222]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

Comment: What are you doing Pilot6? I already accepted the answer on May 28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're asking about: How do I determine if my drivers are up-to-date on Ubuntu.

For starters, you should post the results of `lshw -short` and `nano /etc/os-release` to provide hardware and OS information about your current build.

Now, **assuming** I interpreted your question correctly, the first thing you want to do is make sure your applications are up to date, so run the following:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

Once done here, click on your Unity Dash and search for `checkbox`, run the tests within this application. This will perform [some automated tests](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Automation/Checkbox) (along with tests requiring user input).

Just a side note: Refer to Rmano's answer here about how [Linux uses generic drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524142/how-to-update-all-driver-software-via-terminal).

Now as for the software side of things, if you're still under the impression there are delays, try another browser and see if it software related. To begin testing I would recommend is installing `nethogs` and `bmon` and do some investigation, are there applications that seem to be over-utilizing the network card? If you need a GUI to assist, try `etherape`.

Here is the community fix to an issue relating to yours:

**Fix the bug in Debian Avahi-daemon**

The slow WiFi in Ubuntu problem could also be related to a bug in Avahi-daemon of Debian. Ubuntu and many other Linux distribution are based on Ubuntu so this bug propagates to several Linux distributions. To fix this bug, you have to edit the nsswitch configuration file. Open a terminal and use the following command:

`sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf`

This will open the configuration file in gedit so that you could edit it easily in GUI. In here, look for the following line:

`hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

If you find this file, replace it with the following line:

`hosts: files dns`

Now restart the PC and see if the speed improves.

Here are some links to questions that relate to this issue:

1. [Ubuntu Wireless slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475493/ubuntu-14-04-lts-wired-internet-extremely-slow)
2. [Very slow internet on Ethernet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453940/very-slow-internet-connection-on-ubuntu-14-04)
3. [Internet Slow on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470279/internet-slow-on-ubuntu-14-04)

If this has not assisted, view the article here on "[how to speed up internet](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/)"

Comment: When I opened that file, the line was already hosts: files dns.

Comment: Holy cow, I clicked on the Ubuntu Wireless slow, typed in the sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 <<<"1" they said to do, and now my internet is faster than ever before. Thx

Comment: And how your solution is related to the accepted answer?

Comment: Because I interpreted the question and answered it with valid solutions!

Answer (score 0):

## Answer by the OP

```
sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 <<<"1"
```

in Terminal has made my Internet super fast now. I don't understand why it worked, but I guess all I need is that it works.

Comment: Answer was from a linked question in my answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/475493/ubuntu-14-04-lts-wired-internet-extremely-slow